# Tikzscale undefined control sequence

Tags: tikz-pgf, undefined

I have been working on a revtex project for a while without this problem. Today I moved the project on a new laptop (Mac OS), and installed a fresh TeXShop and TeXLive utilities. When I try to compile the same project, I get:

[image]

I tried deleting the Aux files, reinstalled the tikzscale package (through TeXLive), but the error still persists. How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a minimal document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and reproduces the issue. I have an updated TeXLive installation and can load `tikzscale` without problems.

Comment: Try updating the `pgf` package, there was a problem in an earlier version of it (https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/652) that caused this specific error.